# Alternatives to 'I have got it'

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Let's say I am carrying a couple of bags or something like that and some random stranger offers to carry one of them.

> Do you want me to hold one of these?

I have seen in movies that if you don't have any problem with the bags you will most likely say **I have got it**, rather than saying **No I don't** or explaining how it is not a problem for you to carry the bags which is what I tend to do.

My question is that what else can I use besides this?

Answer (score 7):

The polite thing to say is 'That's very kind of you, but I think I can manage, thank you.'

Answer (score 4):

In general, this phrase is used in situations like what you described: Someone offers to do something, but you don't want/need the help and use this phrase to refuse.

Usually it's said colloquially in it's shortened form, as in "I've got it".

Comment: Or even shorter and more colloquial: *Nah, I got it.*

Comment: Or just as colloquial but a tad more polite: _No thanks, I got it._

Comment: @J.R. Wouldn't it be *No thanks, I've got it*?

Comment: @WendiKidd: Jim's answer was "shorter and more colloquial." Mine was "just as colloquial but a tad more polite." I'd classify your version as "more grammatical and a tad more polite." 8^) Barrie's suggestion, as usual, would be "very courteous and grammatically impeccable."

Comment: Regardless, the reply should include "thanks" or "thank you", since someone offered to help you, even if you refuse it. Otherwise it may be considered rude or self-centered.

Answer (score -1):

- I'm fine thanks.
- No, but thanks for asking.
- I can manage, thanks.
- No, it's ok. Thanks, though.